# Parse Decimal Second by PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like parse a String

`'16:25:20.6598412Z'`

as TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

The function which I use is:

`TO_TIMESTAMP('16:25:20.6598412Z', 'HH24:MI:SS.MSUS')`

but the result is:

`16:25:21.5002+01`

this have not the same time:

`16:25:20.6598412`

Comment: How can `16:25:20.6598412Z` be a timestamp? There is no date part in that string. Which _date_ should Postgres use for that? Don't you want a `time` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `MS` and `US` both in one `to_timezone` call - **microseconds are miliseconds also (and a little more)** so how engine would know how to parse the string?

Instead you should use

```
    TO_TIMESTAMP('16:25:20.6598412Z', 'HH24:MI:SS.US')
```

also notice that `microseconds` due to reference is value in range of (000000-999999) so you can pass 6 digits as US

```
    TO_TIMESTAMP('16:25:20.659841Z', 'HH24:MI:SS.US')
```

---

To loose timezone simply add `::timestamp without time zone;` at the end of `to_timestamp` call

```
    TO_TIMESTAMP('16:25:20.6598412Z', 'HH24:MI:SS.MSUS')::timestamp without time zone;
```